# Missing 'ann' library when ./configure Nova HoneyPot on CentOS machine

Tags: centos, honeypot

I get an error that doesn't let me continue the installation after I issue

```
./configure Nova honeyd
```

The error is that I'm missing the library `ann`, but I have installed the `ann` library using `yum install ann`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my own question in 2 simple steps:

1º: Install the ann library with the following command.

```
$ yum install ann-libs
```

2º: You'll find a file called libANN.so in the directory /usr/lib64, and what you need to do is substitute the capital letters for lowercase, you can achieve this by using the following command while in the /usr/lib64 directory.

```
$ mv libANN.so libann.so
```

Now it should work as it did for me with no problem.